# modify the installation popup for clickonce

Tags: clickonce

Having sorted out an issue with clickonce deployment the client has asked whether we can modify the installation sequences and pretty them up. Can anyone shed any light on how to customise the look and feel of the clickonce initial installer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you are talking about the initial page (publish.htm) that users have to access to install the application?  If so, it's just an html page that you can edit however you wish.

If you are talking about a security warning that users have to click past in order to install your application, then you need to sign your manifest files with a certificate that the client machines trust.  This MSDN link has some information on how to do that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996418.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Once installed you can do all update by code, but I never found a way to skip the initial installation popup.